# Identity Server 4 loggs (Invalid object name 'DeviceCodes') exception

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, exception, client-server, identityserver4

We are using Identity Server 4 for authentication. After upgrading our solution from .Net Core 2.0 to .Net Core 3.1, we started to notice a new exception be logged when a client redirects to our authentication URL, which did not effect the process and everything seems OK for the end  user. The exception is:

```
An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.DbContexts.PersistedGrantDbContext'.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'DeviceCodes'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__164_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
ClientConnectionId:2b07bb46-18fe-4553-a79f-89b0186556d4
Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
```

the query that causes this exception :

```
Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [d].[UserCode], [d].[ClientId], [d].[CreationTime], [d].[Data], [d].[DeviceCode], [d].[Expiration], [d].[SubjectId]
FROM [DeviceCodes] AS [d]
WHERE [d].[Expiration] < GETUTCDATE()
ORDER BY [d].[DeviceCode]
```

We do not have this table '**DeviceCodes**' in our context, Any advice please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the DeviceCodes table which you will get (now that you have upgraded) by adding a migration from the Package Manager Console window like so:

```
add-migration Core3Upgrade -Context PersistedGrantDbContext
```

(Remember to set the correct Startup project in VS and the appropriate Default project in the Package Manager Console according to your setup, else this will fail.)

and then...

```
update-database -Context PersistedGrantDbContext
```

(or run whatever initialise code you may use to seed/apply migrations for your auth database)

If successful, the following SQL should get executed:

```
  Executed DbCommand (27ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  CREATE TABLE [DeviceCodes] (
      [UserCode] nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
      [DeviceCode] nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
      [SubjectId] nvarchar(200) NULL,
      [ClientId] nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
      [CreationTime] datetime2 NOT NULL,
      [Expiration] datetime2 NOT NULL,
      [Data] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_DeviceCodes] PRIMARY KEY ([UserCode])
  );
```